# Is it RESTful for HTTP PATCH to update more than the explicitly provided, during request, fields

Tags: rest, http

I am wondering whether one could design a RESTful API for playing tic tac toe. I want to provide users the ability to create new game, make moves and also make a request for an AI to play on the game, also.

Currently, I have

```
POST /users/{id}/games

With Response
{
    "id": 1,
    "board": "_________",
    "nextPlayer": "X",
    "movesLeft": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    ...
}
```

Does it make sense to provide the "place a move" option like this:

```
PATCH /users/{id}/games/1
{
    "board": "____X____"
}
```

If I issue a PATCH request, providing only the new board, is it okay for the server to persist this, remove a value from the movesLeft property, change who the nextPlayer is, etc...

**Is it RESTful for a PATCH request to not include everything that needs to be changed, however, the server to change it based on business logic?**

Also, is it RESTful to expose an endpoint:

```
POST /users/{id}/games/1/ai/moves
```

which basically makes a move on the board, changes everything accordingly, returns 303 See Other and makes the `Location` header in the Response headers to point to the changed game resource - /maybe even returns the changed game immediately/

I would really appreciate any references, sources, blog posts, examples

Answer (score 0):

> Is it RESTful for a PATCH request to not include everything that needs to be changed, however, the server to change it based on business logic?

Broadly, yes.  HTTP is an agreement about the semantics of the messages (see [Fielding 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)).  [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), like [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), means "make your copy look like my copy".

You want to be a little careful with the response not to imply that the requested changes were accepted "as is" if, in fact the server made unrequested changes to the document as well.  In other words, the client will have its in memory representation of the resource, and we want to be clear in the response whether or not that representation is still accurate.

> is it RESTful to expose an endpoint `POST /users/{id}/games/1/ai/moves` which basically makes a move on the board, changes everything accordingly, returns 303 See Other ...

It's a bit weak.  The problem is [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).  If I'm a *general purpose* client, how am I supposed to know that my cached representation of `/users/{id}/games/1` gets invalidated when I successfully POST to `/users/{id}/games/1/ai/moves` -- there's nothing to tell me that those two resources are related to one another.

What we would normally do instead is POST a "make the ai move" message to `/users/{id}/games/1`.  Now the general purpose client, and also any intermediate components, will know that the representation of the game resource itself has been changed and should be updated.

Comment: Doesn't this statement say that if I return 303 and a Location header, the cache MUST invalidate the game state.
"A cache MUST invalidate the effective Request URI (Section 5.5 of
   [RFC7230]) as well as the URI(s) in the Location and Content-Location
   response header fields (if present) when a non-error status code is
   received in response to an unsafe request method."

Comment: You are absolutely correct -- I'll revise or remove this answer later when I have time.